# Phantomjs loading jquery

Tags: jquery, phantomjs

I'm trying to include/inject jquery into a phantomjs script that I'm writing. But I keep hitting an undefined $ error. Then I took this sample script from Sitepoint but I'm still facing the same issue.

```
var page = require("webpage").create();
var homePage = "http://www.google.com/";

page.open(homePage);
page.onLoadFinished = function(status) {
  var url = page.url;

    page.injectJs("http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js", function() {
      console.log("Loaded jQuery!");
      page.evaluate(function() {
        var searchBox = $(".lst");
        var searchForm = $("form");

        searchBox.val("JSPro");
        searchForm.submit();
      });
    });
    page.render("results.png");
    phantom.exit();
};
```

I have even tried using `window.jQuery` but even that fails.   The same script worked a year ago in the old version of phantom. I'm currently running phantom 1.9.7 on a Mac. I'm not sure if they have changed the includeJs/injectJs module.

Please help me resolve this issue.

Answer (score -1):

`injectJs` injects external JavaScript code from local file **only**.
If you need to inject JavaScript code from an URL, you must use `includeJs`.

Comment: Nope. I've tried injecting from a local file as well. I've also tried toggling between these two commands, but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: First of all, your script will never load jQuery into a WebPage. You have `phantom.exit` in the end of `onLoadFinished` callabck. That means that callback for `page.injectJs` will never be called.